# tty screen instead of normal login during 15.1 upgrade

Tags: login, tty

upgrading to version 15.1 the upgrade process stopped and after rebooting the tty01 screen appeared with a login. i can login but don't know what to do next. how to get rid of the tty: and get to the graphic/window interface or how to proceed with the upgrade?

Comment: What do you see when you press CTRL+ALT+F7 or CTRL+ALT+F8? You go back to your TTY session using CTRL+ALT+F1.

Comment: If what ByteCommander said doesn't work, then does running the command `startx` in the TTY do anything?